# How do I share a variable (bool) between 2 CLI threads?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a function which I want to sleep without delaying the rest of the thread. I don't want to create 2 separate threads for each of the functions to avoid hindering performance. My solution was to create a separate thread which would change the value of a bool every sleep time.

I declare a global bool variable

```
bool sleepcomplete;
```

In one thread I have

```
if (condition)
{
 other function();
 if (condition && sleepcomplete){
   function I want to sleep();
 }
}
```

Now the sleep thread

```
void Sleeper()
{
  sleepcomplete= true;
  Sleep(sleeptime);
  sleepcomplete= false;
  Sleep(sleeptime);
}
```

For some reason the function which I want to sleep does not run at all. Can anybody help me with what I'm doing wrong or offer a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: If `bool sleepcomplete;` is global variable, it's default value is `false`, therefore  `condition && sleepcomplete` can't be true before `sleepingFunction` is run, but that `sleepingFunction` is called after `if(condition && sleepcomplete)`, which means it gets never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sleep without delaying the rest of the thread. You would have to create another thread for that. Also, you cannot simply share global variables between threads because the order of access to that variable is not ever guaranteed. Take a look at mutexes, semaphores, locks, and atomic variables for help.